# echo HINDI language word stored in an array in PHP script

Tags: php, utf-8, echo, meta, hindi

I am trying to echo hindi script words stored in an array. The output is getting displayed when i use `print_r()` but not when i use `echo`. The code is below. what changes do I need to make?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php
$base_arr=array("सूर्योदय","कँगन","ख गोल","गँगरी","घंटाघर","चंचल","छूईमुई","जिज्ञासा","झंकार","टिकट","ठंढाई","डांटना","तौलिया","थकान","दंगल","धुँधला","निंदनीय","पँखुडी","फाइल","बाँटना","भँवर","मंजीरा","यंत्रक","रुकावट","लेकिन","वंचित","शांतनु","षडयंत्र","सँजोग","हिंदुस्तान","अजय","आँकड़े","इंकार","ईखराज","उँगली","ऊगना","एजेंसी","ऐंठना","ओवन","औलाद");
shuffle($base_arr);
print_r($base_arr);
?>

<table border=”1px” bordercolor="#F660AB" bgcolor="#FCDFFF"  width=30% height=50% align=center>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
{
    echo"<tr>";
    for($j=0;$j<6;$j++)
        {
        ?>
         <td> <center><h5><?php echo $base_arr[$i][$j]; ?> </h5></center><
        <?php
        }
        echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: have you tried : http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 1D array as 2D array

Try this:-

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<?php
$base_arr=array("सूर्योदय","कँगन","ख गोल","गँगरी","घंटाघर","चंचल","छूईमुई","जिज्ञासा","झंकार","टिकट","ठंढाई","डांटना","तौलिया","थकान","दंगल","धुँधला","निंदनीय","पँखुडी","फाइल","बाँटना","भँवर","मंजीरा","यंत्रक","रुकावट","लेकिन","वंचित","शांतनु","षडयंत्र","सँजोग","हिंदुस्तान","अजय","आँकड़े","इंकार","ईखराज","उँगली","ऊगना","एजेंसी","ऐंठना","ओवन","औलाद");
shuffle($base_arr);
print_r($base_arr);
?>

<table border=”1px” bordercolor="#F660AB" bgcolor="#FCDFFF"     width=30% height=50% align=center>
<?php
$x =0;
for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
{
echo"<tr>";
for($j=0;$j<6;$j++)
    {
    ?>
     <td> <center><h5><?php echo $base_arr[$x]; ?> </h5></center>
    <?php
    $x++;
    }
    echo"</tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: typo error in haste thank you for pointing it out, it worked for me